# Passing Array from php to Smarty .tpl

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I have been stuck with this for a good while... And I can´t find the way of doing what I want. Heres is my code on my "module.php".

```
$libroarray = array(306,303,302,307);

foreach ($libroarray as $librorow) 
        {
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'image WHERE `id_product` = '.$librorow;
            $results = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql)    ;

                foreach ($results as $row) 
                    {
                    $var = $row['id_image'].' ---- '.$row['id_product'].'<br />';                       
                    }
        }   

        $this->smarty->assign('libros', $var);
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'module.tpl');
```

And I have this on my "module.tpl"

```
{foreach $libros as $item}
{$item}
{/foreach}
```

My problem is that it only displays the last result of "$var"

```
256 ---- 307
```

I tried everything I know... no success!!... I will never understand how to work with arrays. I can´t work them out... I know it only needs a little touch to work, but I simply can´t figure it out

Pleaseee... can anybody help?

Comment: $var is a string not an array... use `$var[] = `

Comment: Dude,That was quick!! And it works... You are a genius! Thanx mate.  Only a little thing: now they display 3 times, each result!

Comment: Sorted!! Just add "LIMIT 1" to the SQL query!! Thanx Rufinus, really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$var` is a string not an array... use `$var[]`

```
$libroarray = array(306,303,302,307);

$var = array();
foreach ($libroarray as $librorow) 
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'image WHERE `id_product` = '.$librorow;
        $results = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql)    ;

            foreach ($results as $row) 
                {
                $var[] = $row['id_image'].' ---- '.$row['id_product'].'<br />';                       
                }
    } 



        $this->smarty->assign('libros', $var);
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'module.tpl');
```

Comment: Please always leave a detailed description and code comments to illustrate what you changed and why it makes a difference.