# I want to send an array from php file to .tpl file in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

when I try to use $smarty->assign('data',$data) in php file
and try to write {$data} in my tpl it gets Null
how to make the tpl file read the value correctly

Comment: It's duplicated question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574148/passing-array-from-php-to-smarty-tpl

Comment: give us fragment of tpl file

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{foreach from=$data item=foo}
{$foo.myitem}
{/foreach}
```

[{foreach},{foreachelse}](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach)